# Local java package on linux

Tags: installation, java

I'm trying to set my local java package as default one

I've already exported path of local java to `bashrc.user` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=~/java7_latest/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:~/java7_latest/bin
```

after souring `bashrc.user` java still shows that its running with version 1.6

`java -version >> java version "1.6.0_20"`

I think that i've done everything correct, so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appended your java bin to the path, therefore if there is one already will take that first. Try the other way around:

> export PATH=~/java7_latest/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Not all programs use JAVA_HOME. You would set it to your Java's main directory, "~/java7_latest" in your case.

For programs looking for the java executable in the PATH Streak's answer will work.

On Debian based distributions (and I think it has been reimplemented for Fedora) there is also the "alternatives" system that lets you switch back and forth between versions. If your distro has it, installing your java would be:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java ~/java7_latest/bin/java
```

This updates the link in /usr/bin/java to point to your installation and you wouldn't need to set the PATH variable. See also the documentation of update-alternatives.